# Elasicsearch getting top 5 results from an aggregation with a script

Tags: ruby-on-rails, elasticsearch

I am trying to get the top 5 products sold, ordered by revenue using elasticsearch in Rails.

Here is my query:

```
  query = { 
    bool: { 
      filter: { 
       bool: { 
         must: [ 
           { term: { store_id: store.id } } # Limiting the products by store
         ] 
       } 
     } 
   } 
 } 

  aggs = { 
    by_revenue: {
      terms: {
        size: 5,
        order: {revenue: "desc"}
      },  
      aggs: {
        revenue: {
          max: {
            script:  "doc['price_as_float'].value * doc['quantity'].value"
          }   
        }   
      }   
    }   
  }   

  response = OrderItem.search(query: query, aggs: aggs, size: 0)
```

I get the error `could not find the appropriate value context to perform aggregation [by_revenue]`

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You need to aggregate orders on product reference, then summing the prices * quantity to get the revenues from one product with a nested sum aggregation, not max:

```
  aggs: {
    products: {
      terms: {
        field: "product_ref",
        order: { revenues: "desc" },
      },
      aggs: {
        revenues: {
          sum: { script: "doc['price_as_float'].value * doc['quantity'].value" }
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

Don't use the size option in the terms aggregation, because you're not sure all the orders for your top products are located in the same shard; you should get them from the response instead.

Comment: It's in the OrderItem index, so there isn't one field per product, it's a collection of every time something is sold. So how you have it would order by most revenue generated from a single product of a single order.

Comment: Ok then you're just missing the aggregation by product reference. Please see my updated answer.

Comment: You are awesome! I have been struggling with this since this morning. Thanks so much!